# Defining builders in multiple plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to add two builders to two different plugins?

My scenario is this. I had a plugin-A that defines nature-A and builder-1 and builder-2, when I created project with this nature, project would get these builders.

Later I introduced another plugin-B that defines nature-B and the same builder-1 and builder-2 as plugin-A. Now when I create project defined by plugin-B, I don't see builder-1 and builder-2 added in .project file. If I remove builders definitions from plugin-A, then project created with plugin-B gets the builders, but not project created with plugin-A.

What is the designer pattern on builder reuse between two plugins?

Comment: So you are using the same builder id for two natures? Not sure what happens if you do that.

Comment: @greg-449 The first one that loads wins. Second one has no builders. Is what I am trying to do even "legal"?

Comment: There isn't a good definition of what is 'legal' here. You could try  putting the builders in a third nature and use 'requires-nature' on the other two

Comment: Thank you this works as intended! Can you post your answer to the question so I can mark it as good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably best to define another nature and put the builders in that nature.

The other two natures can use the `requires-nature` element to specify that they require the nature with the builders.